# Div / Element issue

Tags: javascript, html

Before anyone blasts me, im new to coding. I have tried a couple things and nothing seems to work, And im afraid im sol.

The problem.

```
// Each of these sample items should have a reference to a particular
    // group.
    var sampleItems = [
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Ticker 1", subtitle: "2278.59" , txt1: "+ 11.52", txt2: "+ 0.59%", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: "../../images/Assets/itemUpArrow.png" },
```

I have a api ticker i made, And i usually use

```
<div id="ticker"</div>
```

How ever i cant use this to replace " 2278.59:   subtitle.
Is there any way around this without having to lose my mind ? 
I just want my api data that i get externally to be be in that location.

Update: This is what im trying to do:

```
{ group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Lorem Ipsusssm", subtitle: "<div id="ticker"> </div>", txt1: "+ 11.52", txt2: "+ 0.59%", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: "../../images/Assets/itemUpArrow.png" },
```

How ever I get Javascript runtime error: syntaxerror.

also this

```
Warning 4   Validation (HTML5): Element 'div' cannot be nested within element 'h4'. C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\Development\ah\pages\groupedItems\groupedItems.html   82  55
```

Comment: basically you want change value of subtitle of object of array?

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of that INSIDE THE ARRAY (being `sampleItems`) or do you want to take the 2278.59 and insert it into a div like this: `<div id='ticker'>2278.59</div>` ?

Comment: <div id='ticker'></div>  anywhere else, will output say 8031. straight from the api. I am trying to replace. 2278.59 with that api data so its updating without me manually replacing values.

Answer (score 0):

Not to sure what your questions is but the problem may be that you did not close your div tag.

```
<div id="ticker"> </div>
```

that should fix it but also add a [space] in your div so its not seen as a null value

Comment: No. That was a typo on here. I have tried multiple times to place it in the space of 2278.59. Doesnt work. I always get errors. I dont want static numbers,

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError everytime i try and do   { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Lorem Ipsusssm", subtitle: "<div id="ticker"> </div>", txt1: "+ 11.52", txt2: "+ 0.59%", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: "../../images/Assets/itemUpArrow.png" },

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

Ignore the below if it fails to help, but from your update above:

```
subtitle: "<div id="ticker"> </div>"
```

That is causing your syntax error.  Replace it with this:

```
subtitle: "<div id='ticker'> </div>"
```

---

You forgot the closing `]` on your array (although since there's only one object you should probably just make it a straight object without the brackets).

Choose from these two options:

```
 var sampleItems = [{
     group: sampleGroups[0],
     title: "Ticker 1",
     subtitle: "2278.59",
     txt1: "+ 11.52",
     txt2: "+ 0.59%",
     description: itemDescription,
     content: itemContent,
     backgroundImage: "../../images/Assets/itemUpArrow.png"
 }]
```

**or my suggestion** (*assuming there are no other objects inside this array*):

```
 var sampleItems = {
     group: sampleGroups[0],
     title: "Ticker 1",
     subtitle: "2278.59",
     txt1: "+ 11.52",
     txt2: "+ 0.59%",
     description: itemDescription,
     content: itemContent,
     backgroundImage: "../../images/Assets/itemUpArrow.png"
 }
```

Comment: re-visit my answer I edited with what should help you

Comment: Alright, i have tried the latest thing you said to. It doesnt give me any errors, however, It just shows <div  on the application. And not data from the api.

Comment: I'm sorry I wish I could do more but without the full code I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate the property of object of array and want to change value of this, then it can be useful for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 // group.
 //please remove sampleGroups, itemDescription, itemContent when you use this code
 var sampleGroups = ['f', 'g'];
 var itemDescription= "ss";
 var itemContent= "aa";
    var sampleItems = [
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Ticker 1", subtitle: "2278.59" , txt1: "+ 11.52", txt2: "+ 0.59%", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: "../../images/Assets/itemUpArrow.png" },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Ticker 2", subtitle: "3333", txt1: "+ 11.52", txt2: "+ 0.59%", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: "../../images/Assets/itemUpArrow.png" }
        ];

    //put the value into relaceVal in order which you 
    //want to replace with elements of sampleItems
    var replaceVal = [230, 582];
    for(var i=0; i<sampleItems.length; i++){
        for(key in sampleItems[i]){
            if(key == 'subtitle'){
                sampleItems[i].subtitle = replaceVal[i];
            }
        }
    }

     //alert new value  230, 582 respectively
    alert(sampleItems[0].subtitle);
    alert(sampleItems[1].subtitle);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```